# Rails Custom Routes Using Subroutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have this problem where I'm building a website for a pizzeria where I have for this case two models ProductCategory and Product. Product belongs to a ProductCategory where each category has many Products. I have already named theto product_categories_path  to categories, e.g. product_categories#index => categories, but now I'd want to have links to products index page in path /product_category.name/ but my routes are far from correct.

**Routes.config**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :campaign_products
  resources :opening_hours
  resources :delivery_areas
  resources :contact_infos
  resources :delivery_times
  resources :exceptional_opening_hours
  resources :news
  resources :product_extras
  resources :product_sizes
  resources :payment_options
  resources :product_categories, path: "categories" 

  resources :products do
      get "/product_category.name", to: "products#index", as: :products_path
  end

  resources :pages
  get "/menu", to: "product_categories#index", as: :menu
  root 'pages#index'
```

**product.rb**

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product_category

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 3..30 }, uniqueness: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 4..300 }
    validates :product_category, presence: true
    validates_numericality_of :normal_price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 999.99
    validates_numericality_of :lunch_price, allow_nil: true, :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 999.99
    validates_numericality_of :plus_size_price, allow_nil: true, :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 999.99
end
```

**product_category.rb**

```
class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products

validates :name, presence: true, length: {in: 3..30}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Should I do this in products_controller.rb and index-action where I would have something like:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all.where(:product_category_id == 1)
end
```

Thanks already for all the help!

Comment: I would do `category/:name` for the main listing and `category/{name}/:product_id` for the individual product. You can override `to_param` in the model so that URL helpers use the name instead of the id.